# Cloud Function Returns NULL

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm building a cloud function that is supposed to return document snapshot from Firestore. In the cloud functions logs it console logs the data in the document but when I call it from React-Native it returns null.

Here is the code for the function itself.

```
export const getUserProfile = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const info = admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc("za5rnpK69TQnrvtNEsGDk7b5GGJ3")
      .get()
      .then((documentSnapshot) => {
        console.log("User exists: ", documentSnapshot.exists);

        if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
          console.log("User data: ", documentSnapshot.data());

          documentSnapshot.data();
        }
      });
    resolve(info);
  });
});
```

Also adding in the code from React-Native to call the function.

```
functions()
    .httpsCallable("getUserProfile")({})
    .then(r => console.log(r));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX0dw.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're not dealing with promises correctly.  There's no reason to have the `new Promise` at all here.  (In fact, it's rarely needed - only if you're calling an API that doesn't use promises and only uses callback functions.)  If you're trying to return the contents of the document to the caller, this is all you need:

```
    return admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc("za5rnpK69TQnrvtNEsGDk7b5GGJ3")
      .get()
      .then((documentSnapshot) => {
        if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
          return documentSnapshot.data();
        }
        else {
          return { whatever: 'you want' }
        }
      });
```

You will have to decide what you want the client to receive if there is no document.

Comment: Awesome! That worked for me! To add to that, instead of hard coding the documentID is there a way to pass it in as an argument? 

If I try "firestore().collection("users").doc(docID).get()" I get an unhandled error such as the following:

Unhandled error Error: Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string.

Comment: Yes, that's covered in the documentation for callable functions.  If you have a question about that please post it separately, as there is only one question allowed per post on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Nice man! Thanks for all the help. Checked the documentation and caught my error.